# adjusting images from my api to fill uiimageview of our desired width and height

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview

My application is downloading image files from the api network call, and loading them directly into the tableviewcell uiimageview. Some of those images are smaller and some are bigger in size. I would like to know how to resize an image of any size to our desired uiimageview size in our tableview cell. Please help me with this.

I tried my UIImageview's content modes both "aspectfit" & "aspect-fill" still the images are not sizing to the desired uiimageview size.

Comment: Set the content mode to ``Aspect Fit``. That should resize the images to fit the image view

Comment: "downloading image files from the api network call, loading them directly into the tableviewcell uiimageview" - are you downloading the images in `cellForRow`?

Comment: I solved my issue. Thank you for your insight into this.

Comment: If your downloaded image hasn't exact same ratio as the UIImageView size frame, you'll have to scale it / crop it to be able to adapt the rendering to it.